# Deleting from a view. Mapbasic

Tags: sql, mapinfo, mapbasic

I'm using MapBasic and have used a query to get the rowids (populated in a column) of minimum values

Select SUBSECT_ID, Row, Min(MaxLV)from LVQuery group by SUBSECT_ID into MinLV

Now, I want to delete these entries from the main Table (LVQuery). However I cannot as MapInfo won't let me delete from a view. How do I circumvent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select all the records from the main table which match the ID's in your query results (MinLV). You should then be able to delete those records.

```sql
Select * from LVQuery where RowID = Any(Select Row from MinLV) into ToDelete NoSelect
Delete from ToDelete
```

I think the reason you couldn't delete from MinLV is that it is aggregated data so it wouldn't be clear which records to delete.

Comment: Take really good care when comparing ROWID's between queries. I would recommend using a static ID column instead